# CSS Responsive two column with multi rows into one column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd link an image but I don't have an image gui program on this computer.

So, what is the best approach to get the following to happen.

```
 COLUMN 1 title     COLUMN 2 TITLE
 COLUMN 1 PIES      COLUMN 2 SNEAKERS
 COLUMN 1 TIRES     COLUMN 2 GUITARS
```

And when the screen is minimized, it changes to the following structure.

```
 COLUMN 1 title     
 COLUMN 2 TITLE
 COLUMN 1 PIES      
 COLUMN 2 SNEAKERS
 COLUMN 1 TIRES     
 COLUMN 2 GUITARS
```

The columns basically zip up. What do you feel is the best approach here, to accomplish what I need? CSS is not my forte. Flex ordering?

Comment: it's not a reactjs question

Comment: true, though I am using react for the project, I'll remove the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in `css`, if you want to use `css-flex`

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.part-1,
.part-2 {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .box {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="part-1">
    COLUMN 1 title
  </div>
  <div class="part-2">
    COLUMN 2 TITLE
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="part-1">
    COLUMN 1 PIES
  </div>
  <div class="part-2">
    COLUMN 2 SNEAKERS
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="part-1">
    COLUMN 1 TIRE
  </div>
  <div class="part-2">
    COLUMN 2 GUITARS
  </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/y78npf2j/)

Answer (score 1):

As you are not an expert in CSS what I recommend is that you use a CSS framework such as bootstrap, it would be the easiest way to achieve what you want.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>COLUMN 1 title</p>
      <p>COLUMN 1 PIES</p>
      <p>COLUMN 1 TIRES</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>COLUMN 2 TITLE</p>
      <p>COLUMN 2 SNEAKERS</p>
      <p>COLUMN 2 GUITARS</p>
    </div>    

  </div>
</div>
```

Here you can find more information about your grid layout system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/